# app stopped working when added scroll view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I'm beginner in android development and i want to do scroll view in my application because height isn't enough but when i add it a message "application stopped working" appears

and without it the layout don't appear completely

Xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >


<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/b1" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b3" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b4" />
 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b5" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" /> 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b6" />

 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b7" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b8" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b9" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>  

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />     
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b10" />
<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b11" />
<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b12" />

 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b13" />
<Space
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>    

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s1"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b14" />


 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s2"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b15" />


 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s3"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText3"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b16" />


 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView4"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s4"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText4"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button17"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b17" />


 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView5"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s5"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText5"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b18" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView6"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s6"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText6"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b19" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView7"
  android:layout_width="95dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/s7"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText7"
       android:layout_width="95dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b20" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20px">

<Space
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/b21" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

log cat :

```
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable tostart activityComponentInfo{com.example.aurduino.quad/com.example.aurduino.quad.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:250)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.example.aurduino.quad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-18 13:12:59.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: The ScrollView can host only a direct child. Yours is hosting more than one

Comment: Try removing `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"` from the `ScrollView` because you dont have an `ImageView`

Comment: It says to wrap the whole thing inside the `ScrollView` to a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Did you try it @user3593972 ???

Comment: @blackbelt post it as an answer i think op din't get hold of your comment yet

Comment: sorry i don't know how to wrap whole thing ? , can you explain more ?

Comment: @user3593972 welcome on stackoverflow. Take a look to the link in the top of the post. It contains useful information to help you fixing your issue.

Comment: @Raghunandan, thanks but there is no need

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

`android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"`

from the `ScrollView` because you dont have an `ImageView`

Also, wrap the whole thing inside the `ScrollView` to a `LinearLayout`

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) says

```
A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.
```